# Show Loading GIF, until coordinates are fetched

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Angular code and cordova plugin to get geolocation :

```
$cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition()
        .then(function (position) {
          $scope.map.center.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
          $scope.map.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
          $scope.map.center.zoom = 18;
          $scope.map.markers.now = {
            lat:position.coords.latitude,
            lng:position.coords.longitude,
            focus: true,            
            draggable: false,
            //message: ''
          };

        }
```

Until co-ordinates are fetched and plotted on map, map shows global map
Like these:

[these map is displayed until co-ordinates are fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK4Xc.png)

IONIC HTML CODE:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true">
    <leaflet defaults="map.defaults" center="map.center" markers="map.markers" ng-if="map"></leaflet>
```

Comment: can you clarify your question ?

Comment: On click button `$scope.showLoading = true;` and `$scope.showLoading = false;` in` then` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$scope.loading = true;
$cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition()
        .then(function (position) {
          $scope.loading = false;
          $scope.map.center.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
          $scope.map.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
          $scope.map.center.zoom = 18;
          $scope.map.markers.now = {
            lat:position.coords.latitude,
            lng:position.coords.longitude,
            focus: true,            
            draggable: false,
            //message: ''
          };

        }
```

**Html**

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" title="Dashboard">
    <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true">
       <div class="spinner" ng-if="loading">Loading...</div>
       <leaflet defaults="map.defaults" center="map.center" markers="map.markers" ng-if="map && !loading"></leaflet>
```

Comment: Please check now